# Вычислить среднее значение по колонке в файле

Tags: python, массивы

Пытаюсь вычислить среднее значение оценок учеников в каждом факультете и ничего на ум не приходит. Прошу помощи! Python

```
filename = input('Enter name of file: ')
file = open(filename, 'r')
massive = []
massive1 = []
massive = file.readlines()
for i in massive:
    massive1.append(i.strip().split(','))

#-----Sorting

for i in sorted(massive1, key=lambda ex : (ex[1])):
    print(i)

file.close()

#Конец кода
```

Это часть кода для 1-й части задания, а как посчитать среднюю оценку каждого факультета(3-й параметр)
Вот данные файла с которыми я работал.

```
Cherkas,2002,FizMat,5
Grigorenko,2002,FizMat,5
Sokil,2001,IstFak,5
Konev,2000,IstFak,3
Pulya,2002,IstFak,4
KiMChenIn,1984,FilFak,2
Onegin,2000,FilFak,4
```

На экран должно выводить

```
IstFak: 4
FizMat: 5
FilFak: 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут надо стбрать оценки в словарь. defaultdict упрощает

```
from collections import defaultdict

massive = """Cherkas,2002,FizMat,5
Grigorenko,2002,FizMat,5
Sokil,2001,IstFak,5
Konev,2000,IstFak,3
Pulya,2002,IstFak,4
KiMChenIn,1984,FilFak,2
Onegin,2000,FilFak,4""".splitlines()

massive1 = []
for i in massive:
    massive1.append(i.strip().split(','))
averdict=defaultdict(list)

for i in massive1:
    averdict[i[2]].append(int(i[3]))

for k,v in averdict.items():
    avg = sum(v)/len(v)
    print(k,avg,sep=": ")
```

Comment: Этот код выдает ошибку: NameError: name 'defaultdict' is not defined. + ко всему программа должна читать данные из файла, а тут уже готовый словарь с данными.

Comment: from collections import defaultdict

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не уточнил. Прога должна работать и с моей частью кода, другими словами сортировка которую я делал тоже должна быть и результат должен быть показан на екране, помимо этого должна быть и та часть кода которую кинули и вы. Просто задание которое мне дал преподаватель имеет 2 подзадания А)Сортировка по годам рождения Б) Это посчитать среднюю оценки факультетов и вывести их на экран. А) я сделал, а вот с Б) возникли трудности.

Comment: вот Б) это 7 строчек из моего примера

Comment: а как все-таки вместо уже готовых данных которые вставлены здесь: massive = """Cherkas,2002,FizMat,5
Grigorenko,2002,FizMat,5
Sokil,2001,IstFak,5
Konev,2000,IstFak,3
Pulya,2002,IstFak,4
KiMChenIn,1984,FilFak,2
Onegin,2000,FilFak,4""".splitlines()      сделать так чтобы оно брало их из файла?

Comment: серьёзно? вы свой код посмотрите - там написанно как брать из файла

Comment: Я пытался сделать так же как с 1-й частью кода, но в силу того что я совсем зеленый и у меня не получилось. Я получаю такую вот ошибку: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: зачем splitlines? у вас же readlines! вы вообще читаете что пишите в коде?